# Will changing a VARCHAR(MAX) column to a VARCHAR(500) invalidate a merge replication snapshot in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server-2014, merge-replication

We have a number of columns in a table that were created as `VARCHAR(MAX)` this seems to be causing performance issues with our merge replication.

We don't need these to be `VARCHAR(MAX)` and would like to change them to `VARCHAR(500)`.

Will this invalidate the current snapshot and request a new snapshot to be created? This is a live environment and with the servers being in different continents the snapshot could take a while to transfer, which we need to be prepared for.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who has the same doubts. I can confirm that such a change will not invalidate the snapshot and so will not trigger a new snapshot. We ran the changes and the DDL scripts were simply passed to the subscriber and executed.